# passing the toggle button value to switch button state in another class in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i have an application in which i have 2 tableview controller.In first tableview, i have a button created in my cellforRowAtIndexPath of my first tableview. Initially i have set the button image to 'ON' image which means my alarm is on .Then when i click on the edit button my tableview changes to editmode where i can change my button image to 'OFF'.i want that my button action should be called when the tableview enters in edit mode.This is the code that i have written.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
       NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];
    appDelegate = (StopSnoozeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    TAlarmCell *cell =(TAlarmCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[TAlarmCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        mimageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        mimageButton.frame=CGRectMake(10, 20, 20, 20);   
        mimageButton.tag = 1;     
        [mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_ON.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
        [mimageButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"alarm_OF.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected]; 
        [cell.contentView addSubview:mimageButton];   
    }
    cell.editingAccessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

 return cell;
}
```

//this is my edit code.

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [mTableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];
    if (editing)
    {
        [mimageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(changeMapType:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;

    }
    else {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
        [self.mTableView reloadData];
    }

}
```

//this is my button action

```
-(void)changeMapType:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath =[self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview]]; 

    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row; 
    NSLog(@"row...%d",row);
    appDelegate.changeimagetype = !appDelegate.changeimagetype;
    sender.selected = appDelegate.changeimagetype;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But the problem here is when i click on edit button and tableview enters in edit mode,changeMapType: action is not getting called and my image does not changes.

Answer (score 0):

can u give me some details about

where u r setting this flag

```
if (editing)
```

and for which action of user u want this method to get to called..?

```
-(void)changeMapType:(UIButton *)sender
```

if u want to get called immediately after entering into edit mode, u can use the below method

```
[self performSelector:@selector(changeMapType:)];
```

Comment: i have a button in my tableview with on in it.When i click on the button the image of the button should change for that particular cell only.My problem is when i click on the button the image changes for all the indexpath and after that i want to pass the button state to the switchbutton which is in other class.